# AWS IAM Policy for elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-iam

I am trying to run this cli on a target group:

```
aws elbv2 describe-target-health
```

This IAM policy doesn't work:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1497933736509",
      "Action": [
        "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:::*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Error message:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DescribeTargetHealth operation
```

This works:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1497933977893",
      "Action": [
        "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Question: why do I have to use * to include all AWS resources? Did I miss anything obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some circumstances, paths in ARNs can include a wildcard character or an asterisk (*). But you cannot use a wildcard in the portion of the ARN that specifies the resource type. What does it mean?

You can specify "all users":

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/*"
```

You can specify "all S3 buckets":

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
```

You can specify "all AWS resources":

```
"Resource": "*"
```

The list of valid ARNs is documented at [ARNS and AWS Service Namespaces](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) page. In case of `ELB/ALB` service, the only allowed ARNs and resources are:

```
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:region:account-id:loadbalancer/app/load-balancer-name/load-balancer-id
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:region:account-id:listener/app/load-balancer-name/load-balancer-id/listener-id
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:region:account-id:listener-rule/app/load-balancer-name/load-balancer-id/listener-id/rule-id
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:region:account-id:targetgroup/target-group-name/target-group-id
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:region:account-id:loadbalancer/name
```

In documentation, ARN components in red color are the ones which you can play with. In case of `ELB/ALB` service, you can specify your own `region`, `account-id`, `ELB` name, `target-group-name/target-group-id` etc. etc. But you can't write something like you tried as this is not a valid ARN:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:::*"
```